# Delete page titles

Tags: customization, themes, title

I'm making a website with the Primer theme, and it includes a big bar with the title in huge letters across every page. I prefer the titles be in the body of the post, so I want to delete the title bar altogether.

However, inserts that have been suggested on here like

```
.page_header {
display: none !important;
}
```

don't work at all when I input them into "Additional CSS". What am I doing wrong? Keep in mind, when you answer, that I'm a complete novice.

Comment: More than likely there's an option in the customizer somewhere to hide the page title.  Check with the theme developers if you have trouble finding it.

Comment: No, there isn't any way to do it with the regular tools.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can remove the title tag or you can comment also

```
<?php //the_title(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out manually: It turns out the code I was given didn't specify what part needed to be changed. In the theme I'm using, the title is in
   page-title-container
rather than
   page_header
and it worked just fine once I made that change. Thank you for your help!